# How to enlarge it when clicking on an image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image which I receive from the server. This widget is called `_stationImage`. When I click on an image, I need to enlarge it and darken the background + add a close button (I attached a screenshot below). As I understand it, this can be done using `Hero animations`, but I did not succeed. Tell me how can I implement this?

```
  Widget _stationImage(PublicChargingStationModel station) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 125,
        width: 90,
        child: station.picture != null && station.picture!.isNotEmpty
            ? CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: station.picture!,
                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                  width: 78,
                  height: 116,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: imageProvider,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 78,
                    height: 116,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(
                  Icons.error,
                  color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                ),
              )
            : Image.asset(
                constants.Assets.publicStation,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share entire code, btw it can be made with Hero animations, just wrap your static image with Hero and give it a tag, when it is clicked push a new route which has enlarged image and use same hero tag on that image as well (you can use Dialog if you don't want to cover the entire screen with enlarged image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using showGeneralDialog its work for me...

```
showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Center(
              child:Column(
                 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children:<Widget> [

// add your image & close icon here..

              ],
            ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```